# how to render react component getting error "TypeError: x.IndexPage is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use dynamic import or importing `npm module` in a iife function .I want to use that npm module in my component .is it possible to use like this
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wood-p6e3w?file=/pages/index.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useEffect } from "react";

var x = (async () => {
  const moment = (await import("moment")).default;
  console.log("+++");
  console.log(moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

  function IndexPage({ name }) {
    console.log(moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World.{" "}
        <Link href="/about">
          <a>Abouthhhh</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return {
    IndexPage: IndexPage
  };
})();

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <>{x.IndexPage()}</>;
}
```

what am trying to do is to load `moment` library dynamically so that it will not part of my main bundle to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplification of what's going on here:

```js
var x = (async () => {
  // ...
  return {
    IndexPage: IndexPage
  };
})();

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <>{x.IndexPage()}</>;
}
```

Remember that when you call an async function, it'll *always* give you back a promise. If you want the promised value, you either have to await it, or use a `.then()` handler. In this case, your you're calling your async IIFE, so `x` is going to be a promise. `IndexPage` is not a function on a promise, it's a function on the promised result, so you'll need to await it.

You can't just throw an await into a component - functional components need to run synchronously. Instead, you'll need to design your component to render a loading state while we're waiting for this module to load, and a normal state once it's loaded. Here's one rough example of how to do this:

```js
// x is a promise
var x = (async () => {
  // ...
})();

// The "module" variable represents the module
// we're trying to asynchronously load. It'll be set to null
// until its finished loading in.
let module = null

x.then(loadedModule => {
  module = loadedModule
})

export default function IndexPage() {
  if (!module) {
    // Our module is still loading
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  // Our module has finished loading and we can use it.
  return <>{module.IndexPage()}</>;
}
```

I will note that you're not going to get a performance improvement out of this. You've taken Moment out of your main bundle, but you've made it so the first thing this module does when it runs is load this Moment library. Code splitting works better when you actually wait to load it. For example, if this IndexPage component is the only thing that uses this Moment library, and your page might not use this IndexPage component immediately (e.g. maybe the user has to click on something before the component gets rendered), then you might want to wait to load the Moment library until the first time the component is rendered to the page. (You can move the library-loading logic to a useEffect hook).

Comment: What's the point of using async/await in importing a module ? Shouldn't it import without it ?

Comment: What you're describing is a normal es static import. If the entire module depends on it, then you can just use a static import, and Javascript will fetch the library before running your module. Dynamic imports are meant to be more dynamic - letting you issue the import whenever you want and get notified when the import has finished - which is why it gives you back a promise. It looks like you're currently just trying to emulate static imports with dynamic ones, which is just adding uneeded complexity.